# int? to int Performance

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, casting

I am quite new to programming and I was wondering what kind of performance loss casting an `int?` to an `int` would have? I have a massive 3 dimensional `int?` array and at times I have to cast large amounts to `int`. Would I be taking a large performance hit?

Comment: can you prevent null ints from being inserted?

Comment: _Would I be taking a large performance hit?_ Depends on your code. Most likely the statement before or after takes twice the time.

Comment: There would be no performance loss.

Comment: Write the code. Get a stopwatch. Measure its performance. Then you'll know how fast it is.  **There is no other way to know how fast a piece of code is**. We can't know how fast the code you wrote is, and we certainly do not know whether it is *fast enough to be acceptable to your customer*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the answer in Eric Lippert's blog series on Nullable types starting with [this one](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/20/nullable-micro-optimizations-part-one/).

There he sketches the Nullable struct as

```
struct Nullable<T> where T : struct
{
  ...
  public T Value
  {
    get
    {
      if (!this.HasValue) throw something;
      return this.value;
    }
  }
  public T GetValueOrDefault() 
  {
    return this.value; 
  }
  ... 
}
```

So it's just an `if (bool)` that's added.

Comment: Thats pretty simple, I had thought it was something more complicated.